# Do I need Proof of onward travel when entering India on one-year multiple entry tourist visa as Lithuanian (EU Citizen)?

Tags: air-travel, india, singapore, proof-of-onward-travel, lithuanian-citizens

I am Lithuanian (EU Citizen) and got one-year multiple entry tourist visas for my family.

My entry point will be Kochi (COK) airport from Singapore. I am getting [conflicting information](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293860-i511-k10443333-Proof_of_onward_travel_india-India.html) in regards proof of onward travel when entering India. I would find it somewhat unreasonable to ask for plane tickets one year in advance.

[image]

Do I need Proof of onward travel when entering India on one-year multiple entry tourist visa?

Comment: I have never been asked to show proof of return tickets (sorry, this is just my experience from about a dozen trips, so is not a rule), however there is a max stay duration of 90 days per visit - a longer stay without an intervening exit may result in your visa being withdrawn

Comment: You may be facing a serious problem, Matas!   See Aganju's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asked to provide proof of onward travel on my flight from Singapore to Kochi.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have missed a critical piece - the visa states (third line from the bottom in your photo):
***Continuous stay during each visit not to exceed 90 days*** - you need to leave before the 90 days are full. You can come back multiple times during the year, but you cannot stay the whole year.

With that, having a return trip booked makes a lot more sense. However, as others said, typically they don't ask for proof of the booking.